# Hide column in jQuery MultiColumn Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, multiple-columns

I have a fine working jquery multicolumn autocomplete. Now i have to add a column which should be hidden. Basically its a ID of the values. So when the user selects the value i could able to get the ID of the selected row.

//Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var autocompleteSource;
    var colValues = [];
    var columns = [{ name: 'Workflow Name', width: '200px' }, { name: 'Workflow Category', width: '150px' }, { name: 'Status', width: '100px' }, { name: 'Workflow Owner', width: '150px' }];

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/LoadWorkflowDropdown",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        success: OnComplete,
        error: OnFail
    });
    function OnComplete(result) {

        autocompleteSource = $.parseJSON(result)
        $.each(autocompleteSource, function () {

            colValues.push([this.WorkflowName, this.WorkflowCategory, this.StatusName, this.UserName]);
        });

        $.widget('custom.mcautocomplete', $.ui.autocomplete, {

            _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
                var self = this,
                    thead;

                if (this.options.showHeader) {
                    table = $('<div class="ui-widget-header" style="width:100%"></div>');
                    $.each(this.options.columns, function (index, item) {
                        table.append('<span style="padding:0 4px;float:left;width:' + item.width + ';">' + item.name + '</span>');
                    });
                    table.append('<div style="clear: both;"></div>');
                    ul.append(table);
                }
                $.each(items, function (index, item) {
                    self._renderItem(ul, item);
                });
            },
            _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
                var t = '',
                    result = '';

                $.each(this.options.columns, function (index, column) {
                    t += '<span style="padding:0 4px;float:left;width:' + column.width + ';">' + item[column.valueField ? column.valueField : index] + '</span>'
                });

                result = $('<li></li>').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a class="mcacAnchor">' + t + '<div style="clear: both;"></div></a>').appendTo(ul);
                return result;
            }
        });

        $("#search").mcautocomplete({
            showHeader: true,
            columns: columns,
            source: colValues,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item[0] : '');
                return false;
            }

        });

    }

</script>
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alforno/d3t7V/) here

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Please create fiddle..

Comment: You can add one more attribute to the menu item. Add `data-Id` and assign it the id for that menu. Now in selection you will get selected menu and from there you can get value for this attribute. Let me know if you need help with code.

Comment: @Mritunjay: Sample Fiddle added.

Comment: @khagesh: Can you provide me sample code?.

Comment: you mean you need to get the HEX value??

Comment: @BlankHead: I need to add a column in that which should not be visible for the user. When he selects a row i should be able to get that respective hidden value of the row.

Comment: From where you are getting the ID values? Is it from ajax request?

Comment: From the question i posted above its a ajax request. In the fiddle its a static one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i have modified js code to add unique id to each record and to get that value when user selects a particular option from the auto-suggest list. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srupali/y6xcua5a/)

HTML: Create a hidden field to store the id of selected option

```
<input type="hidden" name="selectedId" id="selectedId" />
```

JS: Added ids in the array and retrieved those ids in `select` function by `index` value.

```
var columns = [{
    name: 'Color',
    width: '100px'},
{
    name: 'Hex',
    width: '70px'}],
    colors = [['Red', '#f00', '1'], ['Green', '#0f0', '2'], ['Blue', '#00f', '3']];

$("#search").mcautocomplete({
    showHeader: true,
    columns: columns,
    source: colors,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#selectedId').val(ui.item[2]);
        this.value = (ui.item ? ui.item[0] : '');
        return false;
    }
});
```